# Extract specific strings

Tags: r, dplyr, gsub

I have already loaded the data in R from various sheets, below you can see the names of the sheets. Below you can see the data and code:

```
df<-data.frame(
                  Tables=c("Export_A1.xlsx","Export_A2.xlsx","Export_A10.xlsx"))
```

[image]

So now I want to extract specific names, or in other words, I want to remove the text "Export_" and ".xlsx". Below you can see an example

[image]

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
df$Tables <- gsub(".*[_]([^.]+)[.].*", "\\1", df$Tables)

df
```

Output:

```
  Tables
1     A1
2     A2
3    A10
```